# Why isn't the run function on my IntelliJ project working? It's greyed out

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The run button on my IntelliJ project is greyed out, and I can't figure out how to run it alternatively. I'm a newbie to programming, so please be gentle.

[image: IDE Screenshot]

Comment: Isn't there a description of the problem when you hover the mouse over the marked portion of your code? If so, what does it tell you?

Comment: If you have a ```public static void main(String... args)``` method then you see a green arrow on the left side of it. Press that arrow and a configuration will be created.

Answer (score 3):

To run a problem you need a recognizable way to launch the program. The most obvious one is to add a `main` method like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Heating().heatingbills();
}
```

This can be called by IntelliJ, or from the command line.

The shortcut for adding this method is to type

```
psvm<tab>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I forgot that I actually still need a main method even if I'm just creating other methods.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click "Add Configuration..."
2. Click the plus on the top left corner
3. Choose "Application"
4. Enter the path of your Main class in the according field